# Play Json Reads and String

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-json

I have the following JSON reader in Play 2.3:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
val airportSearchReads: Reads[String] = (JsPath \ "search").read[String](minLength(3))
```

and the compiler gives me the error

```
diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Reads[M]
starting with method ArrayReads in trait DefaultReads
```

if I use an `implicit val` I get

```
 ambiguous implicit values:
 both value uuidReads in trait DefaultReads of type => play.api.libs.json.Reads[java.util.UUID]
 and value airportSearchReads in object AirportSearch of type => play.api.libs.json.Reads[String]
 match expected type play.api.libs.json.Reads[M]
```

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get a different error, but it works fine for me if I add an explicit type parameter to `minLength`:

```
scala> val airportSearchReads: Reads[String] = (JsPath \ "search").read[String](minLength[String](3))
airportSearchReads: play.api.libs.json.Reads[String] = play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$8@3fee86da
```

I think the problem with leaving that up to the compiler is that there are different combinations of implicits in scope that would satisfy the implicit parameter list of `minLength`.

Answer (score 0):

`DefaultReads` provides readers you need for transforming json values to common types (`String`, `Option`, `Array`, etc.). So providing new readers for `String` is not necessary.

Hence, for accessing a field in your json object you don't need to define a reader, unless you want to read that field into an arbitrary type of yours.

All you need in this case is the constraint which is defined both in `Reads` and `Constraints`. So assuming that your json object is `jsValue` the following code gives you what you want:

```
// val jsValue = ...

(jsValue \ "search").as[String](Reads.minLength(3))
```

Comment: Have your removed your implicit reader? (just delete `val airportSearchReads: Reads[String] = (JsPath \ "search").read[String](minLength(3)` first).

Comment: still the same problem... solution on top works though, so I will use that. thank you very much for your help